# The sum of a DateTime column

Tags: t-sql, datetime

Using T-SQL, how do you find the sum of DateTime values for x amount of records?

Example:

```
id(int) |  name(varchar) |  TimeInWomb(datetime)
---------------------------------------
 id1    |     name1      |     TiW1
 id2    |     name2      |     TiW2
 id3    |     name1      |     TiW3
 id4    |     name1      |     TiW4
  .     |       .        |      .
  .     |       .        |      .
  .     |       .        |      .
```

I want to find the sum of the TimeInWomb's where name = name1.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I admit, in hindsight that was a pretty bad example which I've now changed. By "sum" I mean the sum of the hours/days/weeks/months of all the values where name = name1.

ANSWER:

You can't sum datetimes.

Comment: A "sum" doesn't make sense when referring to dates. What is the sum of two dates supposed to mean? What are you trying to do?

Comment: What would a "sum" of DateTime values even look like?

Comment: Changed example to make it more clear. Sorry about that.

Comment: I still don't get it. You can't sum datetimes, maybe you can illustrate with test data and expected result

Comment: You can't sum datetimes? then thats the answer I guess. I'll have to retrieve the values and then do it using code-behind?

Comment: Well I could add up all the years, months, hours and so far. But I don't see the point in that. It is easy. But if you demonstrate your data and expected result. I am sure there are 100+ people in here ready with a solution. Some of those solutions may even be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed in your edit that you changed your "date of birth" column to "time in womb". Those are two very different concepts. "date of birth" is a SINGLE point in time, where "time in womb" is a DURATION of time. Which of these two concepts are you trying to represent?

- If you're trying to represent a single point in time, then doing a "sum" doesn't make any sense. You can't have a sum of two points in time.
- If you're trying to represent a duration of time, then you shouldn't be using a `DATETIME` column. `DATETIME` is used to refer to a single point in time. You should either have two `DATETIME` columns (a start and an end), or you should have number column (number of seconds, or something similar).

Either way something is conceptually wrong here and we can't give you an answer until you get things sorted out. Some sample data with expected output would help dramatically.

**Edit:**

Since you're trying to represent a duration of time (the time in the womb), then you need to either have two `DATETIME` columns (time of conception and time of birth, for example) or a single number column (seconds in womb, for example). The second option is easier to work with, but the first option gives you more flexibility.

Let's assume that you've got a `SecondsInWomb` column that is a number. The answer to your original question would be:

```
SELECT SUM(SecondsInWomb) FROM table WHERE name = 'name1'
```

That will tell you the total amount of seconds spent in the womb for that name.

Comment: I am trying to represent a DURATION (hence the change and the confession of it being a bad example). But thank you for your response, I have now revised what I am doing with two points in time as you have recommended.

Answer (score 1):

if you are only setting the equivalent of a time for instance you could use SQL's defaults to accomplish your goal by doing the following:

sum(datediff(minutes,'1900-01-01 00:00:00',TimeInWomb)

If you do not set part of a date time function, you would get the MS SQL default for the other portion.  The MS SQL default is 1900-01-01 00:00:00.  If you only set the date, the time is set to 00:00, if you set the time, the date becomes 1900-01-01.

I hope this helps.

Comment: [late comment alert] it should be `minute` instead of `minutes`